# Passing Custom Object List through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, serializable

I am trying to make an app fetching data from JSON and displaying a location on Map using that. The Map mechanism worked fine when the List was getting loaded directly into the activity containing the Map Fragment. Now when trying to load the list in another activity and then trying to send the List via intent, I'm not able to display the data, which I suppose has something to do with the Intent.

This is the Intent sending part

```
if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
        List<AirQuality> receivedData= (List<AirQuality>) data;
        Intent intent = new Intent(AirQualityActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("MYLIST",(Serializable) data);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is the Intent receiving part

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    List<AirQuality> receivedDataList = (List<AirQuality>) b.getSerializable("MYLIST");
```

This is the Custom Object class implementing Serializable

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class AirQuality implements Serializable{
    private String mId;
    private String mStation;
    private String mState;
    private String mCity;
    private String mPollutantID;
    private String mPollutantAvg;
    private String mPollutantMin;
    private String mPollutantMax;

    /*Default Constructor*/
public AirQuality(String id, String station, String state, String city, String pollutantID, String pollutantAvg ,String pollutantMin, String pollutantMax) {
    mId = id;
    mStation = station;
    mState = state;
    mCity = city;
    mPollutantID = pollutantID;
    mPollutantAvg = pollutantAvg;
    mPollutantMin = pollutantMin;
    mPollutantMax = pollutantMax;
}

//Returns Item ID
public  String getId(){
    return  mId;
}

//Returns Station Name
public String getStation() {
    return mStation;
}

//Returns State Name
public String getState() {
    return mState;
}

//Returns City Name
public String getCity(){
    return mCity;
}

//Returns Pollutant ID
public String getPollutantID() {
    return mPollutantID;
}

//Return Pollutant Average value
public String getPollutantAvg() {
    return mPollutantAvg;
}

//Returns Pollutant Minimum value
public String getPollutantMin(){
    return mPollutantMin;
}

//Returns Pollutant Maximum value
public String getPollutantMax(){
    return mPollutantMax;
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm not able to display the data"?

Comment: check what value you are getting in the next Activity.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm getting the parsed JSON data of the type List<AirQuality> in the file AirQualityActivity.java and then sending the received list to MapsActivity.java via intent. In that file's onCreate() method, I put it as a parameter for another method call which makes a certain check and displays location and marker on the Map. I was able to do this when I was getting the list directly in MapsActivity.java but now when I had to get it from another file, I'm not able to. Shows a null object reference error.

Answer (score 0):

firstly I recommended implement to **Parcelable** instead of Serializable. in terms of the following features speed,reflection etc...

answer your question:

**you said  "Now when trying to load the list in another activity and then trying to send the List via intent, I'm not able to display the data"**
i complied your code and it run successfully.it sent the list from firstActivity to secondActivity and then the second is reviewed without any problem.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm getting the parsed JSON data of the type List<AirQuality> in the file AirQualityActivity.java and then sending the received list to MapsActivity.java via intent. In that file's onCreate() method, I put it as a parameter for another method call which makes a certain check and displays location and marker on the Map. I was able to do this when I was getting the list directly in MapsActivity.java but now when I had to get it from another file, I'm not able to. Shows a null object reference error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**AirQuality**

```
public class AirQuality implements Parcelable {
private String mId;
private String mStation;
private String mState;
private String mCity;
private String mPollutantID;
private String mPollutantAvg;
private String mPollutantMin;
private String mPollutantMax;

public AirQuality() {
}

public AirQuality(String mId, String mStation, String mState, String mCity, String mPollutantID, String mPollutantAvg, String mPollutantMin, String mPollutantMax) {
    this.mId = mId;
    this.mStation = mStation;
    this.mState = mState;
    this.mCity = mCity;
    this.mPollutantID = mPollutantID;
    this.mPollutantAvg = mPollutantAvg;
    this.mPollutantMin = mPollutantMin;
    this.mPollutantMax = mPollutantMax;
}

protected AirQuality(Parcel in) {
    mId = in.readString();
    mStation = in.readString();
    mState = in.readString();
    mCity = in.readString();
    mPollutantID = in.readString();
    mPollutantAvg = in.readString();
    mPollutantMin = in.readString();
    mPollutantMax = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<AirQuality> CREATOR = new Creator<AirQuality>() {
    @Override
    public AirQuality createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new AirQuality(in);
    }

    @Override
    public AirQuality[] newArray(int size) {
        return new AirQuality[size];
    }
};

public String getmId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setmId(String mId) {
    this.mId = mId;
}

public String getmStation() {
    return mStation;
}

public void setmStation(String mStation) {
    this.mStation = mStation;
}

public String getmState() {
    return mState;
}

public void setmState(String mState) {
    this.mState = mState;
}

public String getmCity() {
    return mCity;
}

public void setmCity(String mCity) {
    this.mCity = mCity;
}

public String getmPollutantID() {
    return mPollutantID;
}

public void setmPollutantID(String mPollutantID) {
    this.mPollutantID = mPollutantID;
}

public String getmPollutantAvg() {
    return mPollutantAvg;
}

public void setmPollutantAvg(String mPollutantAvg) {
    this.mPollutantAvg = mPollutantAvg;
}

public String getmPollutantMin() {
    return mPollutantMin;
}

public void setmPollutantMin(String mPollutantMin) {
    this.mPollutantMin = mPollutantMin;
}

public String getmPollutantMax() {
    return mPollutantMax;
}

public void setmPollutantMax(String mPollutantMax) {
    this.mPollutantMax = mPollutantMax;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(mId);
    parcel.writeString(mStation);
    parcel.writeString(mState);
    parcel.writeString(mCity);
    parcel.writeString(mPollutantID);
    parcel.writeString(mPollutantAvg);
    parcel.writeString(mPollutantMin);
    parcel.writeString(mPollutantMax);
}
```

}

Intent sending part

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("MYLIST", data);
```

Intent receiving part

```
List<AirQuality> receivedDataList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("MYLIST");
```